# "Could not locate the included file" error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am practicing with Jekyll building a little website from scratch. Unfortunately, the following command returns error:

```
rodolfocangiotti.github.io rodolfo$ bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental --host=0.0.0.0
```

Here is what is printed to `stdout`:

```
Configuration file: /Volumes/Data HD/Jekyll Folder/rodolfocangiotti.github.io/_config.yml
Source: /Volumes/Data HD/Jekyll Folder/rodolfocangiotti.github.io
Destination: /Volumes/Data HD/Jekyll Folder/rodolfocangiotti.github.io/_site
Incremental build: enabled
Generating... 
Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file 'bodyheader.html' in any of ["/Volumes/Data HD/Jekyll Folder/rodolfocangiotti.github.io/_includes", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minima-2.1.1/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source. in /_layouts/default.html
jekyll 3.6.2 | Error:  Could not locate the included file 'bodyheader.html' in any of ["/Volumes/Data HD/Jekyll Folder/rodolfocangiotti.github.io/_includes", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minima-2.1.1/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source.
```

Actually, the `bodyheader.html` file is inside the `_include` folder. Is anyone able to explain why Jekyll is unable to locate that file and how to solve the issue?

**UPDATE:**
The `bodyheader.html` file is included inside the `default.html` file, which is located inside the `_layouts` folder. Here is the content of that file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% include head.html %}
<body>
{% include bodyheader.html %}
{{ content }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What code are you using to include it and from what file?

Comment: @marcanuy I am trying to include `bodyheader.html` inside `_layouts/default.html`. I am going to add its content to the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to rename `_include` folder to `_includes`.